# Image causing vertical alignment problems

Tags: html, css

I have the following div layout:

[image]

Everything is fine when I put normal txt elements in both the blue and the orange div. However, when I place an image in the orange div (which is 31px), the elements in the blue div get pushed down by about half the height of the blue div.

(additional info, when hovering over the html for the orange div in firebug, it seems like only half of the image is contained within it, even though to the naked eye it appears fine).

Would appreciate any help, I'm still a bit rusty on the box model. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the HTML and CSS for this problem?

Comment: Snarky side remark: http://bancomicsans.com/home.html *Please* don't use Comic Sans again, even more when it comes to web design. This font sucks so much... :-)

Comment: lol, it's not the web design. It's a msword abstract mockup of the divs.

Comment: I'm not good in css. but maybe you could try vertical-align: top for the blue box? maybe "float: left" is needed? i believe something with those two

Comment: I know it's a mock-up. But still, that you thought of using it even there just gives me the creeps. :-D

Comment: Can you please provide a working sample?

Comment: Also, why have you changed the orange div's display property from block to inline?

Comment: Wouldn't display:block make the two div's appear below each other instead of next to each other?

Comment: Yes, but changing the display property of one to inline is not the correct solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try floating the image to the left of the text. This way the text will sit next to the image without the need for positioning. For example:

```
<style>
div {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
div img {
height: 31px;
width: 50px;
float: left;
}
</style>

<div>
    <img src="myImage.gif">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

Adjust the layout by giving your container div some padding and/or the image a margin and you should be able to get exactly the look you're after. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try floating the two interal divs.

float:left;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so good with CSS boxes, but could adding: display:inline; to the image style fix the porblem? And/Or adding margin:0px;
Oh and is the brwoser rendering in Quirks mode, since not making it render in Quirks mode could fix some problems too.

**Edit**
By quirks mode I mean, does your page has a DOCTYPE declaration similar to the one below (although you should off course use the corrext DOCTYPE)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

more about DOCTYPES here: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html

Comment: unfortunately not. thanks for suggestion though. And browser is firefox default settings.